# Response of last axios-request response is null

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, axios, callback

I want to get the current **weather** conditions of a given place. In order to achieve that I used two **APIs**. The first one is [Mapbox](https://mapbox.com), which I used to geocode the place name to geo-coordinates, and the second is the [Accuweather](https://developer.accuweather.com) API. I also used the Axios module in order to make  **HTTP requests** to the APIs.

To avoid callback hells and multilayers code and to make it easier to read and maintain I made 3 functions:

1. ***cityToCoordinates*** to get the **latitude** and **longitude** of the place/city name.
2. ***coordinatesToPlaceID*** to get the **place ID** of the coordinates using Accuweather
3. ***placeIDToCurrentForecast*** getting the **current weather** of the place

I made all three functions async since axios requests use **Promises**.

The problem is in the **placeIDToCurrentForecast** function, where the response of the **callback** in the **then** function after calling **coordinatesToPlaceID** is always **undefined** although the request was made successfully and there was a response that I printed.

Here is the script :

```
const axios = require("axios").default || require("axios");

const cityToCoordinates = async (cityName) => {
    const geoCodeBaseURL = " https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/";
    const mapbowAcessToken = "MAPBOX_TOKEN";
    const limit = 1;
    const cityNameUrlEncoded = encodeURIComponent(cityName);

    return await axios
        .get(
            `${geoCodeBaseURL}${cityNameUrlEncoded}.json?access_token=${mapbowAcessToken}&limit=${limit}`
        )
        .then((response) => {
            const responseObject = response.data;

            if (responseObject.features.length === 0) {
                console.log("Sorry no such place exists");
                return;
            } else {
                const location = responseObject.features["0"].center;
                const longitude = location[0];
                const latitude = location[1];

                return {
                    latitude: latitude,
                    longitude: longitude,
                };
            }
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log("An error has occured in city to coordinates");
            // console.log(error);
        });
};

const coordinatesToPlaceID = async (cityName) => {
    const coordinatesToPlaceApiURL = "http://dataservice.accuweather.com/locations/v1/cities/geoposition/search";
    const accuWeatherApiKey = "ACCUWEATHER_API_KEY";

    await cityToCoordinates(cityName).then(async (response) => {
        const query = `${response.latitude},${response.longitude}`;
        const queryUrlEncoded = encodeURIComponent(query);

        return await axios
            .get(
                `${coordinatesToPlaceApiURL}?q=${queryUrlEncoded}&apikey=${accuWeatherApiKey}`
            )
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response.data.Key);
                return response.data.Key;
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log("An error has occured in coordinates to place ID");
                // console.log(error);
            });
    });
};

const placeIDToCurrentForecast = async (cityName) => {
    const placeIdToCurrentWeather = "http://dataservice.accuweather.com/currentconditions/v1/";
    const accuWeatherApiKey = "ACCUWEATHER_API_KEY";

    await coordinatesToPlaceID(cityName).then(async (response) => {
        console.log(response); // Always undefined!!!

        if (response) {
            const placeId = response;

            await axios
                .get(`${placeIdToCurrentWeather}${placeId}?apikey=${accuWeatherApiKey}`)
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log(
                        "The current weathr in " +
                        cityName +
                        " is " +
                        response.data[0].Temperature.Metric.Value +
                        "° C"
                    );
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log("An error has occured in place ID to current forecast");
                    // console.log(error);
                });
        } else {
            console.log("There is no response");
        }
    });
};

placeIDToCurrentForecast("California");
```

The output :

```
332131
undefined
There is no response
```

Why is the response undefined, and how can I **improve** the code?

Comment: Did you try  to add `catch` call to `coordinatesToPlaceID`?

Comment: @Anatoly there is a catch block in coordinatesToPlaceID after then and no exception is thrown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning `undefined` in the `coordinatesToPlaceID` function, check that.
In addition, if you are using `then` you can avoid to use `async-await`, vice-versa

```
const coordinatesToPlaceID = (cityName) => {
    const coordinatesToPlaceApiURL = "http://dataservice.accuweather.com/locations/v1/cities/geoposition/search";
    const accuWeatherApiKey = "ACCUWEATHER_API_KEY";

    return cityToCoordinates(cityName).then((response) => {
        const query = `${response.latitude},${response.longitude}`;
        const queryUrlEncoded = encodeURIComponent(query);

        return axios
            .get(
                `${coordinatesToPlaceApiURL}?q=${queryUrlEncoded}&apikey=${accuWeatherApiKey}`
            )
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response.data.Key);
                return response.data.Key;
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log("An error has occured in coordinates to place ID");
                // console.log(error);
            });
    });
};
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, but still returns undefined

Comment: Why does it print what is supposed to return, console.log(response.data.Key); does not print undefined it prints the response which is the place Id

Comment: Did you add "return" to cityToCoordinates ?

Comment: Yes, I did, I used your answer but same result!!

Comment: Remove all async and check again

Comment: Thank you for the answer it is helpful, I was editing the wrong code (the copy one), and now I am getting the response

Comment: Okay, not a problem